# v3 Youtube API - How to modify the category of a new broadcast

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm trying to define a category for a Youtube broadcast before the livestream is on air.

I've just followed [Youtube API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/life-of-a-broadcast) and I didn't find any snipped definition for `setCategory` method in any class related to broadcasting or livestreaming.
According to that, the only way I've found to define a category is by creating a `Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet` object. Something like this:

```
$videoSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
$videoSnippet->setCategoryId("25");
//            $snippet->setCategoryId($category);

$videoInsert = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
$videoInsert->setSnippet($videoSnippet);

$insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("snippet", $videoInsert);
$updateRequest = $youtube->videos->update("snippet", $videoInsert);
```

Here I let a [link](http://pastebin.com/KF7mKmpD) with the code that makes all the work:

What Am I doing wrongly? Is it a bug?

Thanks in advice.

**UPDATE**

Here bellow I paste the code that helped me solving this problem

```
$listResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos("snippet",
   array('id' => $broadcastsResponse['id']));

$video = $listResponse[0]['snippet'];
$video['categoryId'] = $category;

$updateResponse = $youtube->videos->update("snippet", $video);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the right resource but in a wrong way.

1) you should first create the broadcast with liveBroadcasts.insert()

2) Then with the broadcast/video id you get from that operation, you call videos.update() in that update method, you can set the category.

```
pseudocode:
response = livebroadcast -> insert(broadcast);
video = new video();
video.id = response.broadcastId;
video->setCategory(25);
videos->update(video);
```